# Convert python signing code to javascript

Tags: javascript, python

I'm currently working on a code generator and porting it over to javascript, however I can't seem to get the same results?

The code which I've got in Python is the following:

```py
def sign(self, cs, api):
    temp_string = ""
    cs_length = len(cs)
    api_length = len(api)

    if api_length > 0:
        for index in range(0, cs_length):
            temp_char = cs[index]
            temp_code = ord(temp_char)
            temp_code_2 = ord(api[index % api_length])
            new_code = self.get_code(temp_code, 47, 57, temp_code_2)
            new_char = ""
            if new_code != cs[index]:
                new_char = chr(new_code)
                try:
                    temp_string += new_char
                except:
                    xbmc.log("Unprintable character => %s" % new_char)

            xbmc.log("Index: %i\tCharacter %i:%s\t\tModulus %i\t\tModulus Code %i:%s\t\tNew Code %i:%s" %
                     (index, temp_code, temp_char, (index % api_length), temp_code_2, chr(temp_code_2), new_code,
                      new_char))
    else:
        xbmc.log("Signature cannot be blank")

    # xbmc.log("\r\nTarget Signature: 7a74G7m23Vrp0o5c")
    xbmc.log("Result signature: %s" % temp_string[0:16])

    return temp_string[0:16]

def get_code(self, char_code, const_1, const_2, char_result):
    if const_1 < char_code <= const_2:
        char_code += char_result % (const_2 - const_1)
        if char_code > const_2:
            char_code = char_code - const_2 + const_1

    return char_code
```

And here's what I've wrote in Javascript:

```js
get_code(char_code, const_1, const_2, char_result) {
    if(const_1 < char_code <= const_2) {
        char_code += char_result % (const_2 - const_1);
        if(char_code > const_2) {
            char_code = char_code - const_2 + const_1;
        }
    }
    return char_code;
}

sign(cs, api) {
    let temp_string = '';
    let cs_length = cs.length;
    let api_length = api.length;
    if(api_length > 0) {
        for(let index in this.range(0, cs_length)) {
            let temp_char = cs[index];
            let temp_code = temp_char.charCodeAt(0);
            let temp_code_2 = api[index % api_length].charCodeAt(0);
            let new_code = this.get_code(temp_code, 47, 57, temp_code_2);
            let new_char = "";
            if(new_code != cs[index]) {
                try {
                    new_char = new_code.charCodeAt(0);
                    temp_string += new_char;
                } catch(error) {
                    console.log('"Unprintable character => ' + new_char);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return temp_string.substring(0, 16);
}
```

When running it in Javascript, I'm just getting a ton of `"Unprintable character =>`  results being thrown?

Comment: For future reference: it would be useful to indicate the type of data that the values that are being dealt with - it was assumed that `new_code` was some character, and it was not until a much closer inspection at the Python code at the same line and remember what `chr` and `charCodeAt` actually were that it became clear what the issue was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue appears to be your conversion from this Python code

```py
new_char = chr(new_code)
```

To JavaScript

```js
new_char = new_code.charCodeAt(0);
```

Given that [`chr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr) in Python takes an `int` and return a single length `str`, while [`String.charCodeAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) does the exact opposite - also given that the value of `new_code` appears to be an `Number` or `int` (in JavaScript and Python respectively), that will simply not work as that is not a method available for the `Number` type.

It would have been clear had the code logged the actual `error` inside the `catch` block - the nature of the exception should have revealed that `TypeError: new_code.charCodeAt is not a function`.

You were probably looking for [`String.fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode), so that problematic line should be:

```js
new_char = String.fromCharCode(new_code);
```